# Planet covered in non-Newtonian fluid

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, science-fiction, geology, geophysics

Basically, I watched that horrible holiday special. The animated short that introduced our friend Boba Fett, and there’s a planet that’s apparently covered completely by a non-Newtonian fluid. What kind of conditions would create seas of a non-Newtonian fluid?

Answer (score 4):

According to the Wikipedia page on [Non-Newtonian fluids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid) (emphasis mine)

> A non-Newtonian fluid is a fluid that does not follow Newton's law of viscosity, i.e., constant viscosity independent of stress. In non-Newtonian fluids, viscosity can change when under force to either more liquid or more solid. Ketchup, for example, becomes runnier when shaken and is thus a non-Newtonian fluid. **Many salt solutions** and molten polymers are non-Newtonian fluids,
>
> Many common substances exhibit non-Newtonian flows. These include:
>
> - Soap solutions, cosmetics, and toothpaste
> - Food such as butter, cheese, jam, mayonnaise, soup, taffy, and yogurt
> - Natural substances such as **magma**, **lava**, gums, honey, and extracts such as vanilla extract

The easiest way seems to be cover the planet with magma or lava, which is what happened to Earth and all rocky planets when they formed. Earth also reverted to that state after meeting Theia.

Comment: The lava works, but with that planet from the animated short, if it was, it would be Revenge of the Sith before (and after) Revenge of the Sith. It could be covered in a special kind of mud.